# Regexp give extra matching group

Tags: regex

I have a content which is text mixed with json

```
blablabla  bla bla 
sdf
sdfsdfsdf {
    "glossary": [{
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "val":2
    }]
} dd dfsdfsdf
bla blablablabla
```

I want get json from the string, so I use this regexp

```
\{(.|\s)+\}
```

It gives me (checked it on https://regex101.com/):

- Full match with my correctly found json
- Empty group

I don't understand what causes the empty group to appear

Comment: Use  a mere `\{[\s\S]+}`, `(.|\s)+` is a very inefficient pattern, and it gives you the extra group since it is a (repeated) *capturing* group. What is the language you are using in the target environment (not at regex101)?

Comment: 1) It is not empty, 2) any capturing parentheses will produce a group. Use non-capturing parentheses (`(?:...)`) to avoid creating the group if you don't need one (or indeed a character class, since your problem allows it).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I use python

Comment: Then `re.compile(r'\{.+}', re.DOTALL)` is the solution. Of course, `(?s)\{.+}` will work, too. And *Whenever you are using a capturing group, it always returns a submatch* is the direct answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

This empty group is last new line symbol captured by `\s`. Regex101 even shows you a warning that when you use something like this `(.)+` regex, only the last occurrence of `.` is captured as group. <s>You can use non capturing group `\{(?:.|\s)+\}` to get rid of group or use non capturing group and put second group around quantifier `\{((?:.|\s)+)\}` to have only one group.</s>

Actually, don't do this. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56108708/regexp-give-extra-matching-group/56108846?noredirect=1#comment98851161_56108708) comment and comments below.

Comment: Please never suggest `(?:.|\s)+`, it is a very misfortunate, inefficient pattern that causes crashes, slowdowns, pain (due to excessive backtracking this pattern involves). There are always better alternatives, one is in my top comment to the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew OK, I will keep that in mind.